# Select JSON element greater than 0 to a list

Tags: c#, json, lambda, delegates

I have a Json string from which I want to select and add to a list the elements "initialUnits" with a value greater than 0.
How can I convert "x => x.initialUnits" to integer, so that I am able to test if it a positive or negative value.

I tried "Int32.Parse(x => x.initialUnits)" it gives the error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type".
Or is there an another way to accomplish this?

```
var resultOpTrades = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(Jsontrades);
var Sellopentradeslist = resultOpTrades
                            .trades
                            .Where(x => x.initialUnits > 0)
                            .Select(p => p.price)
                            .ToList()
                            .Select(s => Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(s), 4))
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by this: _convert "x => x.initialUnits" to integer_

Comment: Please, share your json and model

Comment: You don't convert `x => x.initialUnits` to an integer - you convert `x.initialUnits` to an integer, so I suspect you want `Where(x => Int32.Parse(x => x.initialUnits) > 0)`

Comment: `.Where(x =>  Int32.Parse(x.initialUnits) > 0)` .. as `"Int32.Parse(x => x.initialUnits)"` make no sense. The Parse expect a string, x.initialUnits is a string. `x => x.initialUnits` is not, it's a lambda on nothing.

Comment: Imo it's either a Typo or a String to Int duplicate. Without real [mre], the code here does not reproduce the error, nor give enough information so we can provide  a custom converter to the right type for example.

Comment: @Jon Skeet. Thank you. That's exactly  what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Int32.Parse() method takes string as argument. Lambda is anonymous method, passing for Action, Func, Predicate. You cannot give lambda where argument is string. 
You have to take value (using lambda or not), and then do anything you want.